# Text & Data Mining Techniques for Twitter data

Tags: cart

I have been using Statistica tool to do text mining analysis for Twitter data. Can any one tell me what kind of analysis (Text & Data mining) we can do with Twitter data in general. I am very much interested to apply CHAID, C&RT, Decision Trees model on Text data, but no idea how to proceed.

I have both data and the tool (Statistica) but not getting idea like what variables we can predict and how to apply all those data mining concepts with the text data.

If you have any idea please let me know. I am very much interested to learn Text& Data mining concepts.

Answer (score 1):

There are many resources for Twitter analysis. One good place to begin is the book by Kumar, Morstatter and Liu *Twitter Data Analysis* published by Springer. They pretty much cover the waterfront.

Then there are the tutorials on sentiment analysis in Twitter. Having just checked these links today (5/13/2016), they are active and not delinked:

Manoj Kumar, Sentiment Analysis on Twitter Data https://mkmanu.wordpress.com/2014/08/05/sentiment-analysis-on-twitter-data-text-analytics-tutorial/

Sergey Bryl, Twitter sentiment analysis based on affective lexicons with R  http://analyzecore.com/2014/05/11/twitter-sentiment-analysis-based-on-affective-lexicons-in-r/

Then there's this laundry list of sentiment mining links here:
https://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/FBS/sentiment-analysis.html

Of course, you're probably already aware of Twitter's composite index: 
http://blog.texifter.com/index.php/2014/11/20/twitters-complete-index-is-live/

Answer (score 1):

You can read & simultaneously watch videos from **"How to do Text Mining in Statistica"** from this links;
1. http://www.statsoft.com/Products/STATISTICA/Text-Miner
2. https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLA1B7C970F1803850